# divs with "border" properties from their id's in the CSS won't accept "border-radius" properties applied to all divs

Tags: css

I wanted to give all my divs a border-radius of 5px, and I wanted certain divs to have additional border propertied according to their id's.

```
div {
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

#toppanel {
    height: 70px;
    width: 90%;
    margin: auto;
}

#leftpanel {
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    height: 500px;
    border: 5px black solid;
}
```

my #toppanel div now has rounded corners, but my #leftpanel div does not. Does this mean that applying any border properties to a more specific set of elements excludes *any* border-related instructions more generally issued?

Do I need to remove the border-radius instruction from the div{...} instruction, and then add it to every id? Or is there a way to issue the border-radius instruction to all divs at once, while giving different divs different instructions regarding their borders using id's?

I'm currently using jsfiddle inside of a fully-updated Safari on a mid-2012 macbook air.

Comment: Both show border radius to me with Chrome on Win7. Just remember that the inner border radius is scaled and does not necessarily equal the outer border radius due to the thickness of the border, so the inner border radius of `#leftpanel` looks square, but the outer border radius is not. An easy way to check is increase the border radius to 10, in which case the inner border radius should be visibly rounded.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe do

```
#leftpanel , #toppanel{
border-radius:inherit;
}
```